# Use LG 24" LED TV as Primary monitor

Tags: hdmi, monitor, tv

I have a tv that has HDMI input, and a computer with VGA output. (Computer is a Dell Optiplex 360) I have scoured every related question to this forum and have not been successful in my attempt to make my computer recognize my tv when it is plugged in. I am running a fresh copy of ubuntu 14.10. What can I do to make this TV my main monitor?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a couple of years since I had to overcome some difficulty there, but I can give you several hints to push you in the right direction, as I was successful and so should you be.  I recall that using the DISPLAYS utility under the hardware section of systems settings was instrumental, but as it has been so long, I have forgotten exactly how.  I seem to recall you can designate one monitor as primary, but you will probably have to click around a bit in that window to figure out how.

Also it is possible your graphics chipset driver may need to be upgraded in some way to give you some increased control, but I doubt that since it sounds as though you have things working for the most part.

I am not aware of any inherent difference between monitors and TVs with hdmi input which would prevent you from succeeding, but it is possible that the computer associates the last known primary monitor (the one used without the other) for primary use.  You might try disconnecting your old primary monitor entirely to see if that resets matters.

Comment: So, I have no means of plugging in two monitors at once on my computer. My latest attempt was to buy a vga to component cable and plug it in. When I set the tv to Component, nothing happens. When I set the tv to rca, I get a choppy screen on my hd monitor that is impossible to navigate. I tried updating my graphics driver, but that made no difference.